Please confirm my OS image backup plan
I have backing up files down to a science with various solutions. This question is about backing up the OS, installed programs, and configuration changes. Back in the M$ world I used Macrium to make image backups. In the Linux/Unix world I never trusted dd unless I booted to another device. The OS is rather dynamic...
Am I correct that the best (only trustworthy way) to get a good OS image backup is to booth to a live USB stick and use dd to backup to a third storage device? I've tried Clonezilla and really struggled to boot to the USB sticks.

Am I going down the right path?
Do you suggest anything else?
Should I revisit Clonezilla? It has been a few years.

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 real time kernel laptop as a music streamer. I do not want to reinvent it if my Lubuntu 24.04 attempt goes south.

I use Clonezilla all the time. If you have specific issues with it, you could ask about those.

I prefer to backup data, /home, settings I change in /etc and list of installed apps. If you installed any server apps like database or web apps, you also need to back those up. But I do not backup system as that is easy to reinstall. And restore from my backups it relatively easy. I know it works as I have used it to create new install on external SSD that is then almost identical without any effort. I did need a few changes since external drive.

Image backups, even if taken via Live USB, backup the (possibly corrupt)  filesystems on disk. Are you sure this is what you want?

I am seeking a backup of the OS. Yes, it could already be corrupt and it is somewhat easy to reinstall. But I have too many computers each with its own configuration and since this is personal use, my notes of exactly how each one is set up is lacking. I wish I always updated a document when I added an app to changed a config file, but I don't... The goal today is to backup a fully operational device and test drive a different OS to see if it also works well and if it is better. I want to be able to role back. I could buy another SSD drive, but I have plenty of storage to hold an image backup.
